# Join a dynamic number of rows in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
Batch        Items
---+-----    ---+----------+--------
id | size    id | batch_id | quality
---+-----    ---+----------+--------
1  | 10      1  | 1        | 9
2  | 2       2  | 1        | 10
             3  | 2        | 1
             4  | 2        | 2
             5  | 2        | 1
             6  | 2        | 9
```

I have batches of items. They are sent by batches of size `batch.size`. An item is broken if it's quality is <= 3.

I want to know the number of broken items in the last batches sent:

```
batch_id | broken_item_count
---------+---------------------
1        | 0
2        | 2 (and not 3)
```

My idea is the following:

```
SELECT batch.id as batch_id, COUNT(broken_items.*) as broken_item_count
FROM batch
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id
  FROM items
  WHERE items.quality <= 3
  ORDER BY items.id asc 
  LIMIT batch.size -- invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "batch"
) broken_items ON broken_items.batch_id = batch.id
```

(I would `ORDER BY` `items.shipped_at`. But for simplicity, I order by `items.id`)

But this query shows me the error I put as the comment.
**How can I limit the number of joined items based on the `batch.size` that is different for each row** ?

Is there any other way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: Your Postgres version? Are there batches without items? Do you need batches without broken items in the answer? Is performance relevant? If yes, what indexes do you have? Cardinalities? How many broken items per batch typically (min, max)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.id AS batch_id
     , count(i.quality < 4 OR NULL) AS broken_item_count
FROM   batch b
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT batch_id, quality
         , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY batch_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
    FROM   items
    ) i ON i.batch_id = b.id
       AND i.rn <= b.size
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle** with added examples.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c62bd/2)

This is much like [@Clodoaldos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23298840/939860), but with a couple of differences. Most importantly:

- You want to count the `broken items in the last batches sent`, so we have to `ORDER BY id` **`DESC`**
- If there can be batches without items at all you need to use **`LEFT JOIN`** instead of a plain `JOIN` or those batches are excluded.
  Consequently, the check `i.rn <= b.size` needs to move from the `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ddbc1/1)

```
select
    b.id as batch_id,
    count(quality <= 3 or null) as broken_item_count
from
    batch b
    inner join (
        select
            id, quality, batch_id,
            row_number() over (partition by batch_id order by id) as rn
        from items
    ) i on i.batch_id = b.id
where rn <= b.size
group by b.id
order by b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the count of defective items cannot be greater than the batch size.

**EDIT:** After reading your comments, I think using the `RANK()` function, and then join by rank and size should work for you. The following query attempts that.

```
SELECT b.id,
     SUM(CASE WHEN i1.quality <= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0END) as broken_item_count
FROM BATCH as b
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.id, i.batch_id, i.quality, 
               RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY i.batch_id ORDER BY i.id) as RANK
           FROM ITEMS as i) as i1 ON b.id = i1.batch_id AND i1.RANK <= b.size
GROUP BY b.id
```

**EDIT2:** Updated the query with a `LEFT JOIN` to cover the case where there are no samples in some `batch`.

Comment: I don't think this would work: let's say I have a third batch of size `2`, with 3 associated items of quality: `1, 9, 1`. The `broken_item_count` should be 1, your query would return 2. Is that right ?

Comment: Nice touch on the `LEAST()`-function, hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @pinouchon Why would the count be `1`? What value should count as broken?

Comment: @Aquillo You take the last batch of items ordered by item.id ASC, and among those, you check which ones are broken. For the 3rd batch of size 2 I introduced above, the items would be of quality 1, 9 (last one of quality 1 should not be included because the batch size is 2). I don't want to count items that are not in the batch.

Comment: And broken is `less or equal to 3` from what I understand now, but two times `1` would be a count of `2`?

Comment: @pinouchon I have updated my answer with a different approach. Check if that works.